# How to Stub a ReadOnly property of a concrete class

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

Let's say I have a Concrete class with a Read-Only property e.g.

```
public class TestClass
{
   public bool Squid {get;private set;}
}
```

And now I want to stub the response to Squid e.g.

```
Squid squid = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Squid>();
squid.Stub(c => c.Squid).Return(true);
```

However when I run this I get the following error message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

Is there any way of stubbing this property without creating an interface for the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is: Make the property `virtual` as already described in the exception message.

Comment: Without changing the class definition

Comment: How you can imagine this without changing your class definition? Property is read-only and that is. What are you think about reflection?

Comment: @Mark 909: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could use reflection to call the private setter.

Or use reflection to find the backing field and set it directly(A bit harder, but works on non auto-properties with a trivial getter).

And finally it's possible to use the profiling API for that. (AFAIK `Moles` is based on that).

If any of that is a good idea is a different question...